# Does `localStorage.setItem` inside a `setState` fonction affect performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React `setState` can take a callback fonction that return new state and take previousState as argument.

To avoid using a `useCallback` I try to not use the previous state inside a function.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState();

const setValue = (callback) => {
  setState(prev => {
    const newValue = callback(prev);
    localStorage.setItem("demo", JSON.stringify(newValue))
    return newValue;
  })
}
```

I know I can use `useEffect` instead, but I just want to know if this code is ok without `useEffect`

Comment: yes it is ok...

Comment: it's ok like bad practice or like ok but don't do this ? @MedetTleukabiluly

Comment: Nothing terrible will happen here, but this function shouldn't have any side effects.